# Form field not part of rails db model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a field on a form i'm trying to access in the corresponding model, but it is not part of the models database table.  What is the best way to handle this? Is this bad practice?

Comment: What is the relationship between the form field and the data actually persisted in the database table?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is ok to have model attributes that are not in the database table.  These are called **virtual attributes**.

Let's say you want to deal with an attribute called 'virtual_attribute'. Here is how you would deal with it:

While in your form you would have something like this:

```
<%= f.check_box :virtual_attribute %>
```

In your model you would have to do this:

```
attr_accessor :virtual_attribute
```

Notice that this is a built-in Ruby method that gives you the setter and the getter for that attribute:

```
#getter
def virtual_attribute
  @virtual_attribute
end

#setter
def virtual_attribute=(value)
  @virtual_attribute = value
end
```

Comment: Great answer - thanks.  It does seem that my virtual attribute is coming into the model null however.  This is how i'm setting up the field:  <%= text_field_tag :discount_code, nil, name: nil, maxlength: "12", class: "span2" %>

Comment: I'll open it in another question as I believe it warrants it.

Comment: @cman77 could be because you didn't add it to your permitted params in the controller