# form_for with non-model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am using Rails's `form_for` feature to create a form that builds an object. Besides the fields that provide the object's parameters, I want to include a few non-model fields that I can then access in the controller. When I use a non-model symbol for the field, `f.check_box`, Rails throws an undefined method error. Can anyone explain a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form field not part of rails db model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060220/form-field-not-part-of-rails-db-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would get the error because the attribute is not defined on the model.

2 ways I could think of in order to resolve this are:

1. Instead of binding the `f.check_box` to the form, use `check_box` instead, whatever name you call it will be available within the controller.
2. Define an attribute accessor within you model and use it with the `f.check_box`.