# Submit rails form with a field not in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

i need to submit a form, with a select thath not belong to the model. I need this value for other operation after save action, but i receive the error:

```
undefined method `tecnico' for #<Interventi:0x9802cf8>
```

This is part of my form:

```
<%= form_for :interventi, url: welcome_nuovointerventosalva_path do |f| %>

<div class="row">


    <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= f.label :data, 'Data creazione' %>
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> </span>
    <%= f.text_field :data, :class => "date-picker form-control input-mini", readonly: true, :value => Time.now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")  %>
    <!--<span class="help-block">formato YYY-MM-DD</span> -->
  </div>
    </div>

    ....................................
    ....................................

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= f.label 'Tecnico' %>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <%= f.select :tecnico, options_for_select(@tecnici.collect{ |tec| [tec.nome, tec.id] }), {}, class: 'form-control search-select' %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the controller

```
 def nuovointervento
@titolo = "Nuovo Intervento"
@interventi = Interventi.new
@clienti = Clienti.all.order(:nome)
@categorie = Categorie.all
@tecnici = Utenti.where(operatore: '1').order(:nome)
```

end

---

```
private
def parametri_intervento
  params.require(:interventi).permit(:cliente_id, :data, :intervento, :note, :chiuso, :codice, :operator_id, :monteore, :categoria, :referente)
end
```

end

---

Yes, the field 'tecnico' doesn't belong to Interventi model, but in post action, after save, i need this value for other record save with tecnico_id and the created 'intervento' id (it's a join table)

How can i solve?

Tank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form field not part of rails db model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060220/form-field-not-part-of-rails-db-model)

Comment: If there is a join table in picture and a problem like this then you should go for accepts_nested_attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, as MageeWorld sayed, this post was a duplicate.

the answer in
[Form field not part of rails db model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060220/form-field-not-part-of-rails-db-model)
solved my problem!

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

@EffeBi permit this attribute in your controller like other attributes e.g. :data